# How best to render html using javascript based on json from server?

Tags: jquery, json, switch-statement

My server sends json (note the DISPLAY_CHECKBOX var)

`{"MY_DATA":[{"ID":270336,"STATUS":"live","STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER":6,"DISPLAY_CHECKBOX":0},{"ID":224808,"STATUS":"archived","STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER":1,"DISPLAY_CHECKBOX":1},{"ID":139066,"STATUS":"tbd","STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER":2,"DISPLAY_CHECKBOX":0}]}`

I want to loop over the json creating html. My question is how best to handle the switch around the checkbox? ie How to make the checkbox display or not depending on the the DISPLAY_CHECKBOX value?

````
$.each(data.MY_DATA, function(index){

    var myhtml = '<div class="panel panel-default">\
        <div class="panel-heading">\
            if(this.DISPLAY_CHECKBOX == 1) {<input type="checkbox"> }\
        </div>\
        <div class="panel-body">'+this.STATUS+'</div>
    </div>';


    $('#container').append(myhtml);


});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this - using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and a ternary

```
myHtml.push(`<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        ${ this.DISPLAY_CHECKBOX ? `<input type="checkbox">` : "" }
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">${this.STATUS}</div>
</div>`);
```

```js
const data = {
  "MY_DATA": [{
    "ID": 270336,
    "STATUS": "live",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 6,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 0
  }, {
    "ID": 224808,
    "STATUS": "archived",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 1,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 1
  }, {
    "ID": 139066,
    "STATUS": "tbd",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 2,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 0
  }]
}
const myHtml = [];
$.each(data.MY_DATA, function(index) {

  myHtml.push(`<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            ${ this.DISPLAY_CHECKBOX ? `<input type="checkbox">` : "" }
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">${this.STATUS}</div>
    </div>`);
})

$('#container').html(myHtml.join(""));
```

```css
.panel { border: 1px solid black; width:200px; margin:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

For IE11 and under

```
myHtml.push('<div class="panel panel-default">'+
    '<div class="panel-heading">'+
        (this.DISPLAY_CHECKBOX ? '<input type="checkbox">' : "") +
    '</div>' + 
    '<div class="panel-body">'+this.STATUS+'</div>'+
'</div>');
```

```js
const data = {
  "MY_DATA": [{
    "ID": 270336,
    "STATUS": "live",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 6,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 0
  }, {
    "ID": 224808,
    "STATUS": "archived",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 1,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 1
  }, {
    "ID": 139066,
    "STATUS": "tbd",
    "STATUS_DISPLAY_ORDER": 2,
    "DISPLAY_CHECKBOX": 0
  }]
}
const myHtml = [];
$.each(data.MY_DATA, function(index) {

  myHtml.push('<div class="panel panel-default">'+
        '<div class="panel-heading">'+
            (this.DISPLAY_CHECKBOX ? '<input type="checkbox">' : "") +
        '</div>' + 
        '<div class="panel-body">'+this.STATUS+'</div>'+
   '</div>');
})

$('#container').html(myHtml.join(""));
```

```css
.panel { border: 1px solid black; width:200px; margin:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Oh WOW - thanks very much! Am also delighted to see I don't have to escape the line breaks any more - why is that please, is it related to push()?

Comment: No related to  `\`\`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals - you MAY want to keep your concatenations if you need IE support

Comment: I do need IE support (alas) - what are you saying I would do differently to ensure it works in IE please? (Thanks so much for your help)

Comment: Ah I see - ok thank you so much, really appreciate your help